# Time lapse in Virtual Machine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to create a time lapse in Minecraft, but want to try and record and play on the same computer. What I wanted to do was to have a Virtual Machine, in Virtual Box which has Minecraft open with the player positioned in a static place. Then, in the host environment I would host the server and play. Is there a way I can force Virtual Box to be 1080p when minimized so I can do this? Has anyone else done it? I can't find anywhere online that details anything so specific. I wasn't sure if it was more relevant to place this here or on Super User.

Answer (score 4):

I think quite a few people just use a second account and then [a mod like this one](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/646592-v110multishot-timelapse-modv16-camera-coming-soon/) in order to achieve a timelapse. Note that what this mod in particular is doing is really just taking screen shots at a set interval that you then have to mush together into a video file on your own.

Comment: Now all I need to do is force the Virtual Machine to be 1080p. Thanks.